# Apache httpd rewrite mode not work

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd, gitlab

I am using this gitlab config https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab.conf

Here's rewrite log

```
125.121.60.59 - - [14/Aug/2014:12:50:23 +0800]
 [xxx.xxx.com/sid#7f8e26a023c8][rid#7f8e26ca5be8/initial] 
(4) RewriteCond: input='/home/git/gitlab/public/uploads/foo/bar/7b02f4c192/classes.png' pattern='!-f' => matched
```

I am pretty sure `/home/git/gitlab/public/uploads/foo/bar/7b02f4c192/classes.png` exists.

Why the this pattern matched ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`-f` needs the file readable by user run httpd(`apache` on centos).

You may verify it by `sudo -u apache stat /path/to/file`

Comment: If you look at the rewrite the file location `'/home/git/gitlab/public/uploads/foo/bar/7b02f4c192/classes.png' pattern='!-f' => matched` is just what we are expected

Comment: Trust me on this one. That check is done like I have written. I have similar rules on a few servers. From the apache documentation: `REQUEST_FILENAME
    The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request`

Comment: I tried but still not work...

Comment: I had an extra `%`. Please copy both rules and try again. If still doesn't work, check file and folder permissions

Comment: sudo -u apache ls /home/git/gitlab/public/uploads
 ls: cannot access /home/git/gitlab/public/uploads: Permission denied
does it means apache have no permission ? I have change permission by 'chmod a+rx' but not work

Comment: Permissions must be applied recursively. Try setting the apsche group as the group-owner of the folder `public` and make sure all parent folders let apache in.

Comment: %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} works for me after I change the permission